# closed subset bounded away from zero

Tags: general-topology

> Let $A$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $a>0$ for all $a\in A$. Does that imply that there exists $c>0$ such that $a\geq c$ for all $a\in A$?

Does the following work? Let $c=\inf A$. Since $A$ is closed, we have $c\in A$. So $c>0$ and $a\geq c$ for all $a\in A$.

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: There's one tiny case missing from your argument, but other than that it's exactly right.  Make sure you know how to justify $\inf A \in A$!  One can only conclude that $\inf A \in A$ for a closed $A$ if $A$ is non-empty.  But the case where $A = \emptyset$ is very easy to handle separately.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct.  Yet another approach:

Since $A$ is closed, $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ is open, and $0\in \mathbb{R}\setminus A$.  Thus there is some $c>0$ such that $(-c,c)\subset \mathbb{R}\setminus A$, and therefore $a\ge c$ for all $a\in A$.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. This is an alternative one. Assume that such $c$ does not exist, then for any positive integer $n$ there is $a_n\in A$ such that $0<a_n<1/n$. This means that $a_n\to 0$ which implies that $0\in A$ because $A$ is closed. This is against the fact that any element of $A$ is greater than $0$. Contradiction!